# Vespa Tutorial – Pig Failing to connect to local Vespa endpoint: URISyntaxException

Tags: vespa

When following [Vespa's tutorial about blog recommendation](http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/tutorials/blog-recommendation.html.) I ran into an issue connecting to the local Vespa endpoint when calling Pig from the command line with `ENDPOINT=$(hostname):8080`:

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.PigServer - exception during parsing: Error during parsing. Pig script failed to parse: 
<file tutorial_feed_content_and_tensor_vespa.pig, line 131, column 0> pig script failed to validate:
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: localhost:8080
```

This is a bit frustrating for people unfamiliar with Pig following the tutorial step-by-step.

The accepted answer works to get the correct port set.  `Problem with Handshake flying-otter.local:8080` is still an issue but is probably unrelated.

edited to add, if it's of any use: The `Problem with Handshake` seemed to occur when the application was not activated (i.e., deployed but forgot to do the next step).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct usage is

```
-param ENDPOINT=$(hostname) -D vespa.feed.defaultport=8080
```

I see you have gotten around it by rewire the port but using -Dvespa.feed.defaultport will be better for production use cases.

https://github.com/vespa-engine/vespa/pull/3576

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, this fails due to Pig checking that the string is a correct URI.

The not so obvious solution (at least at first...) is simply to add `http://`in front of the hostname so it becomes a valid URI `ENDPOINT="http://localhost:8080"`

The complete call to Pig thus becomes:

```
pig -x local -f tutorial_feed_content_and_tensor_vespa.pig \
    -param VESPA_HADOOP_JAR=vespa-hadoop.jar \
    -param DATA_PATH=trainPosts.json \
    -param TEST_INDICES=blog-job/training_and_test_indices/testing_set_ids \
    -param BLOG_POST_FACTORS=blog-job/user_item_cf/product_features \
    -param USER_FACTORS=blog-job/user_item_cf/user_features \
    -param ENDPOINT=http://$(hostname):8080
```

edit: Well, after running for a (long) while, the issue now becomes, so while the URI is validated, pig seems to add the default port anyway.

```
 com.yahoo.vespa.http.client.core.communication.IOThread cycle
     INFO: Problem with Handshake localhost:8080:4080 ssl=false
```

<sub>At this point I just used `socat` to rewire the 4080 port to 8080 to avoid the need to restart the docker vm :/ `socat tcp-listen:4080,reuseaddr,fork tcp:localhost:8080`</sub>

Comment: Though, this fails at a later stage. Will edit if it's related to this.

Comment: ...And the handshake still fails even though there is no double port specification. Will update when/if I get this to work.